# autosetuprebase vs autosetupmerge

Tags: git

I was just knocking around in my global `.gitconfig` file and I noticed that I've managed to end up with this:

```
[branch]
  autosetupmerge = always
  autosetuprebase = always
```

That seemed more than a little counterintuitive, but after doing some reading, I still have no idea whether I need both or whether it's sufficient to remove `autosetupmerge` and just retain `autosetuprebase`. Most projects that I'm working have a straight downstream->upstream flow, so rebasing is generally preferred when dealing with branches.

Comment: Update the accepted answer please

Answer (score 137, accepted):

What is counterintuitive here is the naming of these preferences. They do look like they refer to the same functionality, but in fact they don't:

- `autosetupmerge` controls whether `git branch` and `git checkout -b` imply the `--track` option, i.e. with your setting of `always`,

  - `git checkout branchname`, if `branchname` exists on a remote but not locally, will create `branchname` tracking its remote counterpart
  - `git checkout -b newbranch` will create a new branch `newbranch` tracking whichever branch you had checked out before issuing this command
- `autosetuprebase` controls whether new branches should be set up to be rebased upon `git pull`, i.e. your setting of `always` will result in branches being set up such that `git pull` always performs a rebase, not a merge. (Be aware that existing branches retain their configuration when you change this option.)

So it makes perfect sense to have both `autosetupmerge = always` and `autosetuprebase = always`; in fact, that's also what I have.

Comment: very nice answer. in short, avoid both and avoid `pull` like the plage. really. you will learn the inner workings of git and end up with a better workflow if you never use `pull`. either `git remote update; git rebase/merge upstream/master` or `git fetch; git rebase upstream/master`... git pull will eventually do something you are not expecting. and then you will not know enough about the inner workings. better to type a little more today and learn than to be in a cusp later that you don't know how to solve :)

Comment: I've got the impression that these both (and even rebase) work very nicely accessing a limited number of remote repos for a handful of projects, all of which mandate the same in-house workflow. I imagine however that your advice would be very sensible for someone who plans to commit to lots of projects with all sorts of different workflows / policies.

Comment: to change this setting for existing branches, use: `git config branch.<branchname>.rebase true`

Comment: `branch.autoSetupMerge=always` doesn't seem to make sense for new branches. Meaning, `git checkout -b b1` would set upstream to branch `master` (generally) of the local repository. What's the point?

Comment: @x-yuri My workflow usually involves staying on my organization's "mainline development" branch (which, in my local repo, tracks the corresponding remote) and any branches that I create will ultimately be meant to be (optionally rebased on top and then) merged into it. Thus, for me, this is practically always what I want, and very convenient. For other workflows, it might not be - that's why it's a preference.

Comment: Same for me, feature branches are to be merged into the master. But `push` is generally used to push changes to a remote repository, and `autoSetupMerge` sets up for it to be the same (local) repository, not remote. Do you not `push` feature branches to remote repositories? Do you use `push` to merge local branches into local master? And only then push the master?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. No, that's not what autosetupmerge is about. You can't push from one local branch to another - pushing is always to a remote. It's just that if you want to update your branch, e.g. by running git rebase, that's what it will rebase on top of by default. And likewise, once you've fetched the upstream, git status will tell you "Your branch and master have diverged and have NN and NN different commits, respectively".

Comment: @laszlok *"...pushing is always to a remote..."* Hmm, I haven't tried it, but according to [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html), a branch can have another branch of the "current local repository" set as its remote. The configuration entries would be `branch.<name>.merge=<other-branch>` and `branch.<name>.remote=.` or `...pushRemote=.`  (note the 'dot' specified in the latter two options).

Comment: @GlennSlayden You can have '.' as your remote - this will be the case when you set up a branch to track another local. And yes you can actually use `git push` to update a local branch, but doing so instead of merge/rebase would be quite unusual.

Comment: I prefer the global option `pull.rebase` over `branch.autosetuprebase`

Answer (score 35):

since this is the first hit, if you search for "autosetuprebase" with google, here an advice:

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

Source https://mislav.net/2010/07/git-tips/

Comment: And since rebasing can cause you to loose the will to live [here's why you shouldn't](http://geekblog.oneandoneis2.org/index.php/2013/04/30/please-stay-away-from-rebase#c6964)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't see any good arguments at your link.

Comment: I wrote this answer five years ago. I don't use it any more. I prefer to merge today. But I am not married with my current git workflow. Maybe I will do it different in the future. The topic "merge vs rebase" has low priority for me today. I love "show history for selection" of my favorite IDE. I care for this much more. If you look at the changes with "show history for selection" it does not matter at all, if rebase of merge was used. The result is important, not the road to it.

Comment: My personal opinion: Some things in live are really important: finding a partner, raising a family, having a cool job, having friends, being curious, stay healthy. I don't participate in the "rebase vs merge" discussion any more. I use what my teams suggests. This leaves more mental energy for important decisions.

Answer (score 28):

It's probably worth mentioning that there is a difference between autosetupmerge=always (in your config) and autosetupmerge=true (the default).

true will only setup merging for remote branches. always will include local branches as well.

You probably want true.

Comment: As of git 2.37+, I would argue you probably want `simple`, instead :)

Answer (score 28):

As I was looking for other possible options of "autosetuprebase" and it took some time to find them, here they are:

```
branch.autosetuprebase
```

When a new branch is created with `git branch` or `git checkout` that tracks another branch, this variable tells Git to set up pull to rebase instead of merge (see "branch..rebase").

- When `never`, rebase is never automatically set to true.
- When `local`, rebase is set to true for tracked branches of other local
  branches.
- When `remote`, rebase is set to true for tracked branches of
  remote-tracking branches.
- When `always`, rebase will be set to true for all tracking branches.

Source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html

Answer (score -16):

You probably don't need to set up autosetupmerge---the default is true.

Comment: As RyanK said below, "always" and "true" result in different behaviour.

Comment: See answer from @laszlok below for an excellent explanation of both `autosetupmerge` and `autosetuprebase`.  See `branch.autosetupmerge` and `branch.autosetupconfig` in the git help for more info: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html.

Comment: For me, the main utility of autosetupmerge=always is that it establishes the upstream relationship of new branches created with git checkout -b. I have no idea why this behaviour is not the default, but it definitely avoids confusion to have this set to 'always'.