# Why is git pull bringing in changes that git fetch rebase is not?

Tags: git, fetch, pull

I have a remote branch 1.4

I did a  `git fetch origin` with the result:

`13b1449..51618fe 1.4 -> origin/1.4`

I then did a `git rebase 13b1449`

git responded `Current branch 1.4 is up to date`

I then did a `git pull origin 1.4` and it brought in 3 files.

What am I doing wrong with the fetch & rebase that is not updating my branch with what it is fetching from the remote serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`13b1449` was the hash of your local commit. The "remote" commit was `51618fe` - the commit you fetched as the head of `origin/v1.4`.

Your `rebase` command did not have any effect (you asked git to rebase on the current commit), the `pull` on the other hand correctly moved your local branch forward.

To avoid confusion, instead of using hashes, you can use branch names :

```
git rebase origin/v1.4
```

---

`git` has several options to apply a `rebase` instead of a `merge` when you pull.

Quoting [this link](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/), found through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480069/autosetuprebase-vs-autosetupmerge) :

## Pull with rebase instead of merge

```
$ git pull --rebase

# e.g. if on branch "master": performs a `git fetch origin`,
# then `git rebase origin/master`
```

Because branch merges in git are recorded with a merge commit, they are supposed to be meaningful—for example, to indicate when a feature has been merged to a release branch. However, during a regular daily workflow where several team members sync a single branch often, the timeline gets polluted with unnecessary micro-merges on regular git pull. Rebasing ensures that the commits are always re-applied so that the history stays linear.

You can configure certain branches to always do this without the --rebase flag:

```
# make `git pull` on master always use rebase
$ git config branch.master.rebase true
```

You can also set up a global option to set the last property for every new tracked branch:

```
# setup rebase for every tracking branch
$ git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

Comment: Makes sense now. I was thinking it was an ellipse in the SHA1, not that there were 2 hashes there.

Answer (score 0):

A `fetch` only retrieves "remote" refs (i.e. refs from a different repository).

A `pull` is actually a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.

If you want the changes from `origin/1.4`, issue this command after you've fetched:
  `git merge origin/1.4`

Comment: I get that fetch only retrieves them, but shouldn't the rebase then apply those changes to my local branch? I'm trying to rebase based on the SHA1 hash. Should I specify the name origin/1.4 instead?